# Copy folder structure on Windows

Tags: windows

I want to replicate the folder structure from a location in another location. Also, I want only the structure which is one level deep to be replicated. Is there a way to do it?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that does that or you need to implement that?

Comment: a tool, I guess that makes this question more relevant to superuser? Could someone move it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use XXCOPY with the /T and /DL switches.

> /DL  Limits processing of directory
>   nesting to n levels.
>
> /T  Creates directory structure, but
>   does not copy files.  It copies
>                all directories including empty ones

http://www.xxcopy.com

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use third party programs, the windows 7 native XCOPY command can also duplicate a folder structure.

```
xcopy source dest /t /e
```

will create the directory structure including empty folder but without copying the files.

Answer (score 4):

[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) supercedes/replaces xcopy in Windows 7, and allows limiting copies to N folder levels deep, e.g.:

```
robocopy <source> <dest> /e /create /lev:2
```

- `/e` includes subfolders, even if empty (use `/s` instead to exclude empty folders)
- `/create` only copies the folder structure and zero-length files
- `/lev:N` limits subfolder traversal to N levels, **including** the `<source>` folder you specified... so `/lev:1` would only include the `<source>` folder itself, and `/lev:2` includes any subfolders immediately under `<source>`, but not their subfolders, and so on

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx for details.

Answer (score 2):

From a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Path\To\Source
for /d %i in (*) do @md "C:\Path\To\Destination\%i"
```

Make sure to quote the destination path to take into account any folders with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Check free Windows tool, [47folders](http://47foldersapp.com/), it was made for it!